# Infopath form raises error when accessed - sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

We have a sharepoint site installed on a domain controlled environment.

the administrator delete the "Authenticated Users" group, then add it again.

then all forms are running good except this form, it gives this error:

There has been an error while processing the form.

An error occurred accessing a data source.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 
Log ID:5566

Any Ideas, and please include steps or workthrough .. thanks

Comment: yes, check the sharepoint logs with the correlation id and post the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better look into the sharepoint logs and search for more information about the error.
"An error occurred accessing a data source" could be anything.

If there is a correlation id, you should use this to find the right error in your shraepoint logs.